# How to change page indicator size of UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, size, uipageviewcontroller

I have created UIPageViewController used tutorial from this [blog](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/)

Now I need to change size of page indicator frame.
I already tried to change frame size of a controller but no success

Here is the code I am using

```
private func createPageViewController() {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let pageController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ImagesPagerViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self


    if contentImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

//Setting appearance globally
private func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Is there a solution to do so?

Comment: Did you get you solution?

Comment: Programmatically I didn't found solution, use answer of Alessandro Ornano

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the position of the embeded UIPageControl, but you can create your own UIPageControl and gain full control over it, notice that im using SnapKit in the following example to set the constraints, you can replace it with your prefered technique  (constraint values in example are pseudocode)

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl()
parentView.addSubview(pageControl)
pageControl.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalTo(yourdesiredWidth)
        make.height.equalTo(yourdesiredHeight)
        make.bottom.equalTo(yourBottom)
        make.centerX.equalTo(yourcenter)
    }
    pageControl.numberOfPages = N 
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page there is the [github link project](https://github.com/jeffaburt/UIPageViewController-Post).

You can simple go to the storyboard and customize your UIPageControl as you needed:

[image]

and you change the frame (and constraints..):

[image]